# How to edit an PNG image per pixel via cli?

Tags: image, png, imagemagick, command-line-interface

Say I have an PNG image where I want to change certain pixels to, say, black. How would I do that?

My guess is that I should take the ImageMagick route. But how would I change, say, pixel ten from the top and from the left to black? To, say, 2% grey etc?

---

EDIT: Since the comment field doesn´t work for code, this addition is directed to eduffys answer:

Thanks. That lead me some of the way, after correcting the syntax. But it doesn´t work quite yes, as I can´t set the colour.

`convert foo.png -draw ‘color 10,10 point’ foo1.png`

works, painting the pixel black

`convert foo.png -draw ‘#cc9999 color 10,10 point’ foo1.png`

Does not return an error but doesn´t do anything visible to the file

`convert foo.png -draw ‘color #cc9999 10,10 point’ foo1.png`

Give me an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine either `convert` or `mogrify` with the `-draw` switch and the `point` command.
Something like this (not tested)

```
 mogrify foo.png -draw 'color 020202 point 10,10'
```

Comment: Thanks. That lead me some of the way, after correcting the syntax. But it doesn´t work quite yes, as I can´t set the colour.

<code>convert foo.png -draw ‘color 10,10 point’ foo1.png</code>

works, painting the pixel black

<code>convert foo.png -draw ‘#cc9999 color 10,10 point’ foo1.png</code>

Does not return an error but doesn´t do anything visible to the file

<code>convert foo.png -draw ‘color #cc9999 10,10 point’ foo1.png</code>

Give me an error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using php script, you can take a look on:
[php graphic](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php).

That way you can execute the script:

```
    # php add_watermark.php myimage.png
```

Previous link has watermark examples too.
You can choose to reeplace the image, or to redirect the output to a file (remember removing HTTP headers).

```
    # php add_watermark.php myimage.png > myimage.wm.png
```

Good luck,